# How to change FontSize By JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, fonts, font-size

This code is not working

```
var span = document.getElementById("span");
span.style.fontsize = "25px";
span.innerHTML = "String";
```

Comment: is it camel cased? `span.style.fontSize = "25px";`

Comment: fontsize -> fontSize
It should be in camel case.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

So, if you want to change the font size, you have to go:

```
span.style.fontSize = "25px";
```

Comment: Looks like it is VS2008's bug. Intellisense providing wrong, it is providing `fontsize` but it should provide `fontSize`. "s" character of word "fontSize" should be capital.

Comment: In JavaScript Intellisense only works meh. It usually provides names, that have already been used so far. That is, if you have declared `fontsize` somewhere, you'll get `fontsize` listed. That has nothing to do with the `.style.fontSize`, however.

Comment: In CSS, though, the property is called `font-size'. Why does it have a different name to access the same property in javascript?

Comment: In CSS font-size is the correct name but in javascript that would trasnlate to font minus style so everywhere in the CSS you have a dash in javascript the property would be camel cased without the dash.

Answer (score 10):

```
<span id="span">HOI</span>
<script>
   var span = document.getElementById("span");
   console.log(span);

   span.style.fontSize = "25px";
   span.innerHTML = "String";
</script>
```

You have two errors in your code:

1. `document.getElementById` -
   This retrieves the element with an Id that is "span", you did not specify an id on the span-element.
2. Capitals in Javascript -
   Also you forgot the capital of Size.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var span = document.getElementById("span");
span.style.fontSize = "25px";
span.innerHTML = "String";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please never do this in real projects:

```js
document.getElementById("span").innerHTML = "String".fontsize(25);
```

```html
<span id="span"></span>
```

Comment: This is so awful I couldn't just pass along without upvoting. People need to know about this, specifically, not doing this!

Answer (score 0):

```
span.style.fontSize = "25px";
```

use this

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this was my original HTML:

```
<input id = "fsize" placeholder = "Font Size" type = "number">
</input>

<button id = "apfsizeid" onclick = "apfsize()"> Apply Font Size 
</button>

<textarea id = "tarea"> Your Text 
</textarea>
```

And this was my original JS:

```
function(apfsize) {
var fsize = document.getElementById("fsize").value;
var text = document.getElementById("tarea").innerHTML;
text.style.fontsize = fsize;
document.getElementById("tarea").innerHTML = text;
}
```

This is my new JS, and it seems to be working just fine:

```
function apfsize() {
var fsize = document.getElementById("fsize").value;
fsize = Number(fsize);
document.getElementById("tarea").style.fontSize = fsize + "px";
}
```

So for some reason, I had to add the little "px" at the very last as a string, and somehow it worked. I hope this helps :)