# Changing Font Size in Cordova App by Userinput

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova

So created this nice app. Some testers go test. Some are older folks, don't have good eye sight. Want bigger font. So we make Settings Page: fonts for everyone.

Good, not problem. Everything text in css `font-size` has `em`. But is cordova app. So HTML is loaded quite a number of times. There goes [Javascript DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586703/how-to-change-fontsize-by-javascript) stuff.

Still not problem. We have [view-port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194940/phonegap-application-text-and-layout-too-small/15545381#15545381).

Are there other ways to do this? Quite a number of HTML parts are deleted and others are put back in, so to add a `class` to an element does not work.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/28943502/2026740

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it: It is not a changing of the font-size, it is an abibity for the user to zoom, or, actually: `user-scalable=yes`

Old:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Into:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```