# how to change site font-size with a +/- button

Tags: javascript

how to Use JavaScript to create the functionality to increase / decrease the font size used on the website. The basic functionality should include two buttons - a button to make the font size smaller and a button to make the font size larger?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change FontSize By JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586703/how-to-change-fontsize-by-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the `click` event of the two buttons, and change the font size of the document according to the `id` of the clicked button using `document.body.style.fontSize` as follows:

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("changeFontSize");
for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
     buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
          if(e.target.id == "increase")
               document.body.style.fontSize = "20px";
          else if(e.target.id == "decrease")
               document.body.style.fontSize = "10px";
     })
}
```

```html
<button id="increase" class="changeFontSize" type="button">Increase</button>
<button id="decrease" class="changeFontSize" type="button">Decrease</button>
<p>Hello</p>
```

Comment: Should increment by a %(20% I suggest) and not set a fixed number, because for AODA, you can click the button more than once. For my projects, we did 20% and 5 clicks gets you to 200% which is max