# How to change the fontsize property of html element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello Im new at html css and javascript and I have been having some problems trying to change the fontsize of the elements of a class using javascript.

For some reason when I change the fontsize of the elements in the function resize_element it doesnt work, any suggestions??

This is what I have so far:

```js
// Create Elements
var images_names = ["Images/article_0.svg", "Images/article_1.svg", "Images/article_2.svg", "Images/article_3.svg", "Images/article_4.svg",
"Images/article_5.svg", "Images/article_6.svg", "Images/article_7.svg", "Images/article_8.svg" ]
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images_names.length; i++) {
  // Create div
  var divAnunci = document.createElement('div');
  divAnunci.setAttribute('class','divAnunci');
  // Create link
  var linkvar = document.createElement('a');
  linkvar.setAttribute('href','https://www.youtube.com/');
  var text = document.createTextNode("Buy Now");
  linkvar.appendChild(text);
  // Create images
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = images_names[i];
  img.setAttribute('onclick','two()');
  // Create titol
  var titol = document.createElement('p');
  titol.setAttribute('class','titol');
  var text = document.createTextNode("A very nice random title");
  titol.appendChild(text);
  // Create description
  var descripcio = document.createElement('p');
  descripcio.setAttribute('class','descripcio');
  var text = document.createTextNode("A very nice random longer description");
  descripcio.appendChild(text);
  // Append titiol, descripcio, link and image to div
  divAnunci.appendChild(titol);
  divAnunci.appendChild(img);
  divAnunci.appendChild(descripcio);
  divAnunci.appendChild(linkvar);
  // Append divanunci to main div
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divAnunci);
  }

// Geometry function
function resize_element(num){
  var i;
  // Resize whole div
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("divAnunci");
  var widthsize = 100/num-0.1;
  widthsize = widthsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = widthsize+"%";
  }
  // Change font titols
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("titol");
  i = 0;
  var fontsize = 2.2*4/num;
  fontsize = fontsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontsize = fontsize+"vw";
    // elements[i].setAttribute('font-size',fontsize+"vw");
  }
  // Change font descripcions
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("descripcio");
  i = 0;
  var fontsize = 1.5*4/num;
  fontsize = fontsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontsize = fontsize+"vw";
    // elements[i].setAttribute('font-size', fontsize+"vw");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

/* Contenidor que conte el header */
.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}

/* Contenidor que conte tots els anuncis */
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
}

/* Contenidor que conforma anunci */
.divAnunci {
  /* background-color: #f2ce6b; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 24%;
}

/* Imatge dels productes */
img {
  width:100%;
}

/* Titol dels productes */
.titol {
  font-size:2.2vw;
}

/* Descripcio dels productes */
.descripcio {
  font-size:1.5vw;
}

/* Lik dels productes */
a{
  width: 50%;
}

a:link, a:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover, a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>SOME TITLE</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<!-- Header -->
<div class="header">
  <h1>NICE TITLE</h1>
  <p>Click on the buttons to change the grid view.</p>
  <button onclick="resize_element(2)">2</button>
  <button onclick="resize_element(4)">4</button>
  <button onclick="resize_element(8)">8</button>
  <button onclick="resize_element(16)">16</button>
</div>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are facing the same problem as faced in this question  [How to change FontSize By JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586703/how-to-change-fontsize-by-javascript) -- namely, it is camel-cased as `fontSize`, not `fontsize` as you have it.

Comment: You have the wrong variable name for font size. It is case sensitive and in camel case as all javascript equivalents are. elements[i].style.fontSize instead of elements[i].style.fontsize

Comment: you shouldn't change the font size through Javascript you should have CSS classes with all possible font sizes your application supports

Answer (score 0):

Here is one:

> change `fontsize` to `fontSize`

```js
// Create Elements
var images_names = ["Images/article_0.svg", "Images/article_1.svg", "Images/article_2.svg", "Images/article_3.svg", "Images/article_4.svg",
  "Images/article_5.svg", "Images/article_6.svg", "Images/article_7.svg", "Images/article_8.svg"
]
var i;
for (i = 0; i < images_names.length; i++) {
  // Create div
  var divAnunci = document.createElement('div');
  divAnunci.setAttribute('class', 'divAnunci');
  // Create link
  var linkvar = document.createElement('a');
  linkvar.setAttribute('href', 'https://www.youtube.com/');
  var text = document.createTextNode("Buy Now");
  linkvar.appendChild(text);
  // Create images
  var img = document.createElement('img');
  img.src = images_names[i];
  img.setAttribute('onclick', 'two()');
  // Create titol
  var titol = document.createElement('p');
  titol.setAttribute('class', 'titol');
  var text = document.createTextNode("A very nice random title");
  titol.appendChild(text);
  // Create description
  var descripcio = document.createElement('p');
  descripcio.setAttribute('class', 'descripcio');
  var text = document.createTextNode("A very nice random longer description");
  descripcio.appendChild(text);
  // Append titiol, descripcio, link and image to div
  divAnunci.appendChild(titol);
  divAnunci.appendChild(img);
  divAnunci.appendChild(descripcio);
  divAnunci.appendChild(linkvar);
  // Append divanunci to main div
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(divAnunci);
}

// Geometry function
function resize_element(num) {
  var i;
  // Resize whole div
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("divAnunci");
  var widthsize = 100 / num - 0.1;
  widthsize = widthsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.width = widthsize + "%";
  }
  // Change font titols
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("titol");
  i = 0;
  var fontsize = 2.2 * 4 / num;
  fontsize = fontsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontSize = fontsize + "vw";
    // elements[i].setAttribute('font-size',fontsize+"vw");
  }
  // Change font descripcions
  elements = document.getElementsByClassName("descripcio");
  i = 0;
  var fontsize = 1.5 * 4 / num;
  fontsize = fontsize.toString();
  for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.fontSize = fontsize + "vw";
    // elements[i].setAttribute('font-size', fontsize+"vw");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* Contenidor que conte el header */

.header {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 32px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: white;
}


/* Contenidor que conte tots els anuncis */

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: space-between;
}


/* Contenidor que conforma anunci */

.divAnunci {
  /* background-color: #f2ce6b; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 24%;
}


/* Imatge dels productes */

img {
  width: 100%;
}


/* Titol dels productes */

.titol {
  font-size: 2.2vw;
}


/* Descripcio dels productes */

.descripcio {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
}


/* Lik dels productes */

a {
  width: 50%;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- Header -->
  <div class="header">
    <h1>NICE TITLE</h1>
    <p>Click on the buttons to change the grid view.</p>
    <button onclick="resize_element(2)">2</button>
    <button onclick="resize_element(4)">4</button>
    <button onclick="resize_element(8)">8</button>
    <button onclick="resize_element(16)">16</button>
  </div>

  <div id="container">
  </div>

</body>
```